# find the value of t to make the paraboloid function always positive

Tags: linear-algebra

i've stumbled upon this problem:

Given a bilinear form check if it's positive definite,

$B_t(v,u) = xx' -2xy' -2x'y + tyy'$

now a bilinear form is definite positive if the associated
quadratic is positive:

$x^2 -4xy +ty^2$

and from what i've seen on geogebra, this is the equation of a paraboloid,
i've tried finding the eigenvalues to use the signature but it's quite a mess,

there is another way to find the answer?

Thanks for reading thus far!

Comment: *Hint:* $x^2 -4xy +ty^2 = (x-2y)^2 + (t-4)y^2$